# Not able to read properties from properties files in a class having `main` method in springboot app for local testing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

This class is not able to read values from the properties files for my spring-boot application--

This is the structure of my project-

[image: Project structure]

I am able to access the values of the properties from both
`application-dev.properties` and `config.properties` in my `HomeController.java` class.

But I am getting the values as `null` in my `ClientUtility.java` class

**HomeControlller.java**

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;
    @Autowired
    private PropertyService propertyService;

    @Value("${customer.auth.key}")
    private  String customerAuthKey;

    @Autowired
    private EntityToDtoMapper mapper;

    @GetMapping(path="/customer/{id}",produces= {"application/xml"})
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerDto> getCustomer(@PathVariable("id")int id ,@RequestHeader("authKey") String language){
        System.out.println(propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer());
        if(language.equals(customerAuthKey)) {
        CustomerDto customerDto=customerService.getCustomer(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(customerDto, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

**ClientUtility.java**

```
@Component
public class ClientUtility {

    @Value("${customer.auth.key}")
    private String customerAuthKey;

    @Autowired
    private PropertyService propertyService;

    public void getCustomers() {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/customer/1";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        // add basic authentication header
        headers.set("authKey", "6AE-BH3-24F-67FG-76G-345G-AGF6H");
        System.out.println(customerAuthKey);
        System.out.println(propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer());
        // build the request
        HttpEntity<CustomerDto> request = new HttpEntity<CustomerDto>(headers);

        ResponseEntity<CustomerDto> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, CustomerDto.class);
        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            System.out.println("Request Successful.");
            System.out.println(response.getBody().getFirstName());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Request Failed");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ClientUtility clientUtility = new ClientUtility();
        clientUtility.getCustomers();

    }

}
}
```

Output

```
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.spring.liquibase.demo.utility.ClientUtility.getCustomers(ClientUtility.java:33)
    at com.spring.liquibase.demo.utility.ClientUtility.main(ClientUtility.java:53)
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.com=DEBUG
local.server.port=8080
```

**application-dev.properties**

```
# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liqbtest?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=liqbtest
spring.datasource.password=liqbtest

# Hibernate
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
customer.auth.key = 6AE-BH3-24F-67FG-76G-345G-AGF6H
```

**config.properties**

```
auth.key.to.add.customer=6AE-BH3-24F-67FG-76G-345G-AGF6H
```

**PropertyService.class**

```
package com.spring.liquibase.demo.utility;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class PropertyService {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String getKeytoAddCustomer() {
        return env.getProperty("auth.key.to.add.customer");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using  ClientUtility clientUtility = new ClientUtility() it wont get autowired.

Comment: @Autowired
private ApplicationContext context; Then use context.getBean(SomeClass.class)

Comment: @Autowired cannot be used inside the main class. I think this`main` class is creating the trouble. It is detaching all the spring beans and loading a fresh application context ..something like this maybe

Comment: Also is ClientUtility you main class?

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee looks like you are trying to do local testing with the `static void main` method. In that case, hard coding value is fine to test the functionality. But, if you want to test if the `ClientUtility` class is actually taking the value from `properties` file then you will have to run the complete Spring Boot application and call the `getCustomers()` method.

Comment: Yes , i think so. So, u mean i have to find out some other way to call the `getCustomers()` method other than calling it in a `main method`. I can create another `rest method`, where i will call a  `method` of another class inside that `method` i can call `getCustomers()` . This will enable me to pick the values from prop file right?

Comment: @TomJava is `ClientUtility.java` is another main class

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee  - You will end up starting two applications running in parallel. No need to write a separate main class. Just call this from another class from controller.

Comment: I wanted to test `Resttemplate.exchange() ` thats y I went for thi sapporach, or else `POSTMAN` was enough to test. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

Here when you use  ClientUtility clientUtility = new ClientUtility() it wont get autowired
so properties wont get picked up. So I would suggest to use

```
//Inside main method
ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(ClientUtility .class, args);
ClientUtility clientUtility = applicationContext.getBean(ClientUtility.class);     
clientUtility.getCustomers();
```

Then it should work

Comment: Its not working, i am getting `null pointer exception` inside main in this line `ClientUtility clientUtility = context.getBean(ClientUtility.class)`

Comment: can u try this one?

Comment: `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.` --do i need to change the port and run? Does this run my spring boot app again?

Comment: Are you trying to test the code with another main program?

Comment: pls see the project structure, as i said it is a springboot application. here I am trying to consume a rest uri of the same application. So, i had a main method inside another class. If i hardcode the properties it works.

Comment: Sorry to say, why you want to consume the rest application? So already your Spring boot is running, on top of that you are running another java program - say a spring application.

Comment: Even after changing the port it is not working. `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.`

Comment: Yes, i was just testing and trying to see how can i consume the the employee details, so instead of creating a separate application we can do that using another main method, there are other ways as well.

Comment: if your aim is to consume your restful api, then it is better to move to a test class.

Comment: I don t think so we will be able to read from prop file if we have another main method in the spring boot application.

Comment: You have two options to test your restful apis 1) Use a post man application 2) Write a junit to invoke the url and proceed.

Comment: yes using `Postman` its working fine! I wanted to test out `RestTemplate.exchange(/....)` thats y i treid this. No issues! thanks for helping me out~!

Answer (score 0):

As TomJava already mentioned, that is a great way to use properties.
Another safe and sound way is to use the properties as a normal java bean and then utilise them.

Example:

in application-dev.properties, use

- acme.enabled, with a value of false by default.
- acme.remote-address, with a type that can be coerced from String.
- acme.security.username, with a nested "security" object whose name is
  determined by the name of the property. In particular, the return
  type is not used at all there and could have been SecurityProperties.
- acme.security.password.
- acme.security.roles, with a collection of String that defaults to
  USER.

```
package com.example;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties("acme")
public class AcmeProperties {

    private boolean enabled;

    private InetAddress remoteAddress;

    private final Security security = new Security();

    public boolean isEnabled() { ... }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) { ... }

    public InetAddress getRemoteAddress() { ... }

    public void setRemoteAddress(InetAddress remoteAddress) { ... }

    public Security getSecurity() { ... }

    public static class Security {

        private String username;

        private String password;

        private List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton("USER"));

        public String getUsername() { ... }

        public void setUsername(String username) { ... }

        public String getPassword() { ... }

        public void setPassword(String password) { ... }

        public List<String> getRoles() { ... }

        public void setRoles(List<String> roles) { ... }

    }
}
```

Taken from [this spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config)

Comment: Maybe it's out of scope...but thanks, by looking at this code I've found why properties were not loading in my app... I forgot to define the sub-class as static (Security class in your example)

Answer (score 0):

Use @`PropertySources` Spring Annotation like follows.

```
@Component
@PropertySources(value={@PropertySource("classpath:application-dev.properties")})
public class ClientUtility {

    @Value("${customer.auth.key}")
    private String customerAuthKey;
```

Why can't you read the property value in Property service by Spring annotations itself?

**PropertyService.class**

```
package com.spring.liquibase.demo.utility;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:config.properties")
public class PropertyService {

    @Value("${auth.key.to.add.customer}")
    private String authKey;

    public String getKeytoAddCustomer() {
        return authKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: seems the null pointer is throwing from propertyService. if the line 33 in ClientUtility is System.out.println(propertyService.getKeytoAddCustomer()) please add the code of PropertyService class.

Comment: `PropertyService` is fine , controller is able  to get its value. I have added the code of the same pls have a look at it.

Comment: See, there are two prop file-- `config.prop` and `application-dev.prop` for these two prop files i am accessing in diff ways. For `config.prop` i am accessing using `PropertySAervice` for the other i am using @Value. The point is I am nt able to get the value of both of these files in `ClientUtility` class

Comment: what is exact at the ClientUtility.java line number 33 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213247/discussion-between-thilankad-and-arpan-banerjee).